# How to solve 'Failed to find stack for package [pose_follower] & [sbpl_lattice_planner]?

Tags: ros, 3d-navigation, sbpl-lattice-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [3d_navigation](http://ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation).

After downloading, I run

```
  rosmake --rosdep-install 3d_navigation
```

It shows:

```
 sam@sam:~/code/ros/navigation/sam_3D_navigation$ rosmake      --rosdep-install 3d_navigation
 [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['3d_navigation']                                                                                   
 [ rosmake ] Logging to      directory/home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120417-212956                                                   
 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['3d_navigation'] to:
 ['3d_nav_executive', 'pose_follower_3d', 'octomap_collision_check',      'sbpl_lattice_planner_3d', '3d_nav_gazebo']
 [ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may      take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .    
 Failed to find stack for package [pose_follower]
 Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [pose_follower]:Cannot locate      installation of package pose_follower: [rospack] couldn't find package      [pose_follower]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros]      ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/sam/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
 Failed to find stack for package [sbpl_lattice_planner]
 Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [sbpl_lattice_planner]:Cannot locate      installation of package sbpl_lattice_planner: [rospack] couldn't find package      [sbpl_lattice_planner]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros]      ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/sam/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
 Failed to find stack for package [pose_follower]
 Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [pose_follower]:Cannot locate      installation of package pose_follower: [rospack] couldn't find package      [pose_follower]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros]      ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/sam/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
 Failed to find stack for package [sbpl_lattice_planner]
 Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [sbpl_lattice_planner]:Cannot locate      installation of package sbpl_lattice_planner: [rospack] couldn't find package      [sbpl_lattice_planner]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros]      ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/sam/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31997/how-to-solve-%27failed-to-find-stack-for-package-%5Bpose_follower%5D-&-%5Bsbpl_lattice_planner%5D?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For these particular errors, install the navigation_experimental stack containing the packages [pose_follower](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pose_follower) and [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_lattice_planner). If you follow the instructions, just replace "diamondback" with "electric" in the ubuntu package list.

However, there will be more errors after that since there were significant changes in the arm_navigation parts used in 3d_navigation and the code linked in the Wiki is only compatible with diamondback. A version for electric or fuerte is currently worked on.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-17**:
What you mean is I should wait until 3d_navigation could be installed in /opt? Thank you~

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-04-17**:
Yes, unless you want to invest much time in patching yourself.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-17**:
Is there any schedule for this integration? Thank you~

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-04-17**:
It's being worked on. You could try what is available at https://kforge.ros.org/Sushi/trac but there is no official release (and no support) yet with the latest (and fastest) implementation.